# create same table in a if and else statement, which shows error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
if @id is null
    select
        id
    into #id
    from table_info
else
    select
        if
    into #id     -- This shows : There is already an object name '#id' in the database.
    from table_info i
    where i.id=@id
```

This is the first part in my procedure, if there is an id input, it will only calculate the related info on the id, if not, it will calculate all ids.

I think I could create a table and insert info into. Is there a way to solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done by having the WHERE clause do all the checking:

```
select id
into #id
from table_info i
where @id is null or i.id = @id
```

Comment: @Jens It does solve the OP's problem, though.  Because it removes the need to even do the `if`/`else` with two `#id` tables.

Comment: Thanks, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `ISNULL`

```
select id
into #id
from table_info i
where i.id = ISNULL(@id, i.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, you could just explicitly create the table first, then use `INSERT INTO` rather than `SELECT INTO`:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT)

IF @id IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT #T (ID) 
    SELECT ID 
    FROM table_info;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT #T (ID) 
    SELECT ID 
    FROM table_info 
    WHERE ID = @ID;     
END
```

Or you could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID
INTO #T
FROM table_info 
WHERE @ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID
FROM table_info 
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

The other solution posted using `WHERE ID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL` would work, but I would approach this with caution as depending on your data you could end up with a suboptimal execution plan.

For a very quick example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table_info', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table_info;
CREATE TABLE #table_info  (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Filler CHAR(1));
INSERT #table_info (ID)
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id)
FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b;
```

Now, for some benchmark tests:

```
SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM #table_info;
SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM #table_info WHERE ID = 50000;
```

This gives the following plans:

[image]

So if we specify an ID, we can perform an index seek rather than an index scan, which is much much quicker (0% vs 100%).

Now, a test with parameters:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM #Table_info WHERE ID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID INT', 50000;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID INT', NULL;
```

Which gives:

[image]

The problem is that since the optmiser doesn't know at compile time whether or not `@ID` will be null or have a value, it has to build a plan that would work for both, so either way uses the much slower clustered index scan.

If we use the `IF` control flow, as in the question, then the optimiser is once again able to choose the best plan:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'IF @ID IS NULL 
                                SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM #Table_info; 
                            ELSE  
                                SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM #Table_info WHERE ID = @ID;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID INT', 50000;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ID INT', NULL;
```

Plans:

[image]

*n.b. using `UNION` has the same affect as this, since it is two select statements, two plans are generated, both will be optimal*

You can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to ensure that using `OR` you get the best plan depending on the value of the parameter (and avoids parameter sniffing), so there are workarounds, you just need to work out which solution is best for you. I generally prefer to explicitly create a table anyway, so I would usually tend towards doing this and keeping your `IF` statement.